# I got an assert.js:383 throw error while running deploy.js file which I made for a solidity project. What should I do?

Tags: javascript, npm, solidity, smartcontracts

Here is the terminal output

```
[sohampadia@localhost inbox]$ node deploy.js 

assert.js:383

throw err;
^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback object specified.
    at runWithCallbacks(/home/sohampadia/solidityprojs/inbox/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:97:7)
    at compileStandard(/home/sohampadia/solidityprojs/inbox/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:207:14)
    at Object.compileStandardWrapper [as compile] (/home/sohampadia/solidityprojs/inbox/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:214:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sohampadia/solidityprojs/inbox/compile.js:8:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sohampadia/solidityprojs/inbox/deploy.js:3:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
    generatedMessage: false,
    code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
    actual: false,
    expected: true,
    operator: '=='
}**
```

Details-

- npm --version
  6.14.12
- mocha@8.3.2
- ganache-cli@6.12.2
- web3 // latest version

If you want any more details , I'm happy to give you.

Here is my solidity file contents

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Inbox{
    string public message;
    function Inbox(string initialMessage) public {
        message=initialMessage;
    }
    function setMessage(string newMessage) public{
        message=newMessage;
    }
}
```

Here is my deploy.js file contents

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const { interface, bytecode } = require('./compile');
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    'apple apple apple apple apple apple apple apple apple bee bee 
bee',
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/qwertyuiopasbdhne'
);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const deploy = async () => {
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts(); 
console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
  .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!'] })
  .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] }); 
console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

Here is my compile(javascript) file contents

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname , 'contracts' , 
'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf-8');
module.exports = solc.compile(source,1).contracts[':Inbox'];
```

Comment: Please edit your question and share the `deploy.js` and the Solidity file as well.

Comment: @PetrHejda , Ive included necessary codes with edited personal info. im just learning about smart contracts

Comment: I've seen few variations of the same (incorrect) code in few other StackOverflow questions. Do you have an URL of the page where you got the code? I'll try contacting the author to fix it on their page... This answer should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/66867643/1693192

Comment: Actually , the author teaches in udemy  and his course is 3 years old , and the code  worked 3 years ago. Btw thank you for your help

Comment: @PetrHejda please check out this post too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67084414/i-have-a-problem-in-my-compile-js-file-for-a-solidity-project