# why am i getting an AssertionError error in solidity Smart Contract testing?

Tags: javascript, solidity

**test.js  file**
I was trying to make some tests on Contracr and received an `AssertionError` error, below is the code which I have written.

```
const provider = ganache.provider();
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const {interface,bytecode} = require('../compile');
let accounts;
let inbox;
beforeEach(async() => {
  
  accounts =await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  
  inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
      .deploy({
        data: bytecode,
        arguments: ['Hi there!']
      })
      .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });
  inbox.setProvider(provider);
});
describe('inbox',()=>{
  it('deploys',()=>{
      assert.ok(inbox.options.address);
  });
  it('has some default message', async () =>{
    const message = await inbox.methods.message().call();
    assert.equal(message, 'Hi there');
  });
});
```

**the out put I got from terminal**

I am getting the error as

```
  1 passing (615ms)
  1 failing

  1) inbox
       has some default message:

      AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: '' == 'Hi there'
      + expected - actual

      +Hi there
      
      at Context.it (test/Inbox.test.js:28:12)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

**compile.js file**

This is the code I have written to compile my contrace.

```
 const path = require('path');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const solc = require('solc');
    
 const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts','inbox.sol');
 const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf8');
    
 module.exports = solc.compile(source,1).contracts[':Index'];
```

**inbox.sol file**

This is my Contract.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
contract Index{
    string public message;
    function Inbox(string  _reqstring) public {
        message = _reqstring;
    }
    function setMess(string  _init) public {
        message = _init;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected token '\[' when running Solidity test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66863563/unexpected-token-when-running-solidity-test)

Comment: The name of your contract is `Index`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Also, what version of web3 are you using?

Comment: Thanks alllot( @wxker)  my contract name has to be Inbox. it's my mistake. Thnak you.